# Update Foreign Key with softDeletes()

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I've been looking for the similar solution but can't find anywhere. I don't even know if there is one. What I am trying to do is perform a `softDelete` on one of my model and want to update the `user_id` in the model with the the `id` of the user performing the action. I have tried using `associate()`, it doesn't throw any exception but does not work. I mean the delete is working but `id` is not updating

Here's what I've tried

```
public function postDelete(Request $request){
   $appointment = \App\Models\emp_appointment::findOrFail($request->appid);
   $user = $request->user();
   $appointment->user()->associate($user);
   $appointment->delete();
}
```

Here's my Appointment Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class emp_appointment extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function employee(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\employee','emp_id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\tb_login','userid');
    }
}
```

PS: There are no problems in the models and no errors anywhere. Only the problem is `userid` doesn't get updated in the appointment table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the delete method isn't saving your change (association)

Try saving first then deleting

```
public function postDelete(Request $request){
   $appointment = \App\Models\emp_appointment::findOrFail($request->appid);
   $user = $request->user();
   $appointment->user()->associate($user);
   $appointment->save();
   $appointment->delete();
}
```

EDIT

```
public function postDelete(Request $request){
   $appointment = \App\Models\emp_appointment::findOrFail($request->appid);
   $user = $request->user();
   $appointment->user()->associate($user);
   $appointment->deleted_at= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $appointment->save();
}
```

Comment: But I think this will execute two different query. I was thinking if there's anyway I could do this in a single query.

Comment: yes, this will execute two queries. I assume you use softDelete, in that case you could manually delete it, see edit